# ManyToOne Hibernate - Retrieve in group

Tags: hibernate

We have 2 tables with ManyToOne relationship. I want to retrieve records from table that has many records for a particular id from 'one' table. Is there a pre-defined api/method to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You could either get the specific "One" Object from the session using Session.get(Class clazz, Serializable id) and use Hibernate.initialize(Object proxy) Method to initialize its "records" manually or use Criteria API or HQL query to Fetch the "records". Or use Hibernate Lazy Loading feature.